# Why is the click event not being registered in the associated javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When I click a link in the page, it doesn't always register in the javascript. This is a MVC solution and this is one of the views encapsulated within a Site.Master page.

This First example works.
Page: (someView.aspx)

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add", "AgentNotesCreate", "AgentNotes", new { id = Model.AgentId }, new { @class="addLink"} )%>
```

(rendered link)

```
<a class="addLink" href="/AgentNotes/AgentNotesCreate/152">Add</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$(document).on("click", "a.addLink", function () {
    var newHref = $(this).attr("href");

    if (newHref.split("?").length > 1) {
        // There's already a query string attached - we're adding our own on top.
        newHref += "&returnToken=" + $("#page_redirect_token").val();
    }
    else {
        // We're adding the only querystring parameter
        newHref += "?returnToken=" + $("#page_redirect_token").val();
    }

    $(this).attr("href", newHref);
});
```

});

However, this second example which also references the same javascript above, does not work - it goes to the $(document)... line and then skips the entire function so no returnToken has been added to the URL.

Second Example: (someSecondView.aspx)

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("Add", "EMDProductShelfCreate", "EMDProductShelf", new{id = Model.PersonId}, new{@class="addLink"} ) %>
```

(rendered link)

```
<a class="addLink" href="/EMDProductShelf/EMDProductShelfCreate/45">Add</a>
```

Comment: don't you preventDefault?

Comment: That looks right, can you provide the rendered markup for the link that isn't working?

Comment: The javascript was written by someone else but I am using it... and it works fine for the first ActionLink item.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include rendered markup for both links (working and non)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the positioning of where the ActionLinks are on the page? Try switching their placement and seeing if the same ActionLink still has the problem.

Comment: I did change the positioning with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question was originally written, your first example of a rendered link:

```
<a href='#' class="deleteAgentNotes">Delete</a>
```

does not match the selector `"a.addLink"` in your event handler:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addLink", function () {
```

thus, when you click on that rendered link, it doesn't match the event handler so nothing happens.  If that's the rendered link you want this line of code to work for, then it should be this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteAgentNotes", function () {
```

Also, since I see that you're changing the `href` on the click upon link, you should realize that the delegated event handler runs AFTER the click is processed on the actual link so an href in the link will be acted up first and if that takes the browser to a new page, the delegated event handler won't even get a chance to run.  So, basically it's not possible to use delegated event handling to OVERRIDE the behavior of a link because the default behavior will have already happened before the delegated event handlers gets a shot at the event.  If the ONLY behavior you want the link to have is via your delegated event handler, then you probably want to change the `<a>` tag to a `<span>` so there is no default handling for the click handler and then process the click entirely in your event handler.  If you want to take the user to a new page upon the click, then just do `window.location = "your url"` in the event handler.  There is no requirement to use a link for that.

Comment: Thanks for showing me - I had copied the wrong line of rendered HTML. I have updated my question to show this

Comment: @silvenwolf - OK, then read the paragraph I just added to my answer as you may have a different issue.

Comment: I follow you, but then how would this apply to the first ActionLink for AgentNotes which works - it goes into the javascript and appends the returntoken to the end of the link? It's the second one (ActionLink for EMDProductShelf) that although written in the same format, does not work.

Comment: @silvenwolf - you will have to describe what you're really trying to accomplish as I don't understand from the code snippet.  Why are you trying to change an href of a link that is clicked on?  It won't affect the current click, only future clicks.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort in helping - all I wanted to know was why one link would call the javascript and the other one wouldn't. As it turns out, I had other js errors on that page that caused the problems to happen.